# Can I use NSString inside system("");?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, tweak

I am currently working on a tweak where the user writes the argument of a command (e.g. sbalert from sbutils) via a preference bundle. I am able to save it to an NSString but not able to use it as the argument of the sbalert command. Is this possible? Is there and alternative? My code is

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {

NSString *string1 = @"Hello World";
NSLog(@"%@", string1);
system(" sbalert -t %@", string1);

    return 0;
}

// vim:ft=objc
```

Note that this is a test, so the NSString is not equal to the text in the Preference Bundle still theos gives me an error while compiling.

Comment: Tried man 3 system or NSString class reference? So obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The `system` function doesn't take a format string, and even if it did, you couldn't use the %@ format specifier - that's for Cocoa only and not available in the C standard library. You have to preformat your string like:

```
NSString *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sbalert -t '%@'", string1];
system([cmd UTF8String]);
```